# Dozer Mapping of deep Property mapping

Tags: xml, dozer

I am a newbie to Dozer and have these three classes

```
class PersonEntity {
    Set<AddressEntity> addresses; 
}

class Person {
    AddressList addresses;
}

class AddressList {
    List<Address> address;
}
```

Is there a way to get dozer mapping written for this?

Here is what I have so far

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>domain.entity.AddressEntity</class-a>
    <class-b bean-factory="org.dozer.factory.JAXBBeanFactory">
        com.rackspace.customer.Address
    </class-b>

    <field>
        <a get-method="isPrimary">isPrimary</a>
        <b set-method="setPrimary">primary</b>
    </field>
</mapping>

<mapping>
    <class-a>domain.entity.PersonEntity</class-a>
    <class-b bean-factory="org.dozer.factory.JAXBBeanFactory">com.rackspace.customer.Contact</class-b>

    <field>
        <a>userId</a>
        <b>username</b>
    </field>

    <field custom-converter="domain.converter.PersonNumberAdapter">
        <a>personNumber</a>
        <b>contactNumber</b>
    </field>

    <field>
        <a>addresses</a>
        <b>addresses.address</b>
        <a-hint>domain.entity.AddressEntity</a-hint>
        <b-hint>com.rackspace.customer.Address</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

How do you tell the second mapper to reuse existing mapper for converting AddressEntity to Address and vice versa?
This does not work, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<b is-accessible="true">addresses.address</b>
```

Ok After an hour of debugging I found out that it was trying to access my setter methods to set values, since my JAXB objects do not have any setters on them it failed.

Once I added the is-accessible to true it worked like a charm.

From Dozer FAQ

**Will the getter and setter methods be invoked when fields are mapped?**

Yes. You can bypass this default behavior by explicitly specifying is-accessible="true" for any of your mappings. If is-accessible is specified, the field(including private fields) is accessed directly and the getter/setter methods are bypassed. It is not recommended that you set is-accessible="true", unless you are dealing with an unorthodox data object that does not contain any getter or setter methods.